# using getline with cin to specify user input

Tags: c++

Everytime there is an error with the input type in this function, it automatically sets the value of *_cost to 0.  Why is this happening?

```
void Item::setCost(string input){
float entered;
istringstream stin;
stin.str(input);
if(!(stin >> entered)){
    do{
        cout << "invalid input" << endl;
        stin.clear();
        getline(cin, input);
        stin.str(input);
        *_cost = entered;
    }
    while(!(stin >> entered));
}
else{
    *_cost = entered;
}
}
```

I use the function in my main function as follows:

```
istringstream stin;
string input;

cout << "enter cost" << endl;
getline(cin, input);
items[i]->setCost(input);
```

Comment: _'I am a new c++ programmer.'_ Sick of this, just waste of bandwidth!! We know by looking at your question (I'm **really** grumpy today, wasting bandwidth as I like to) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `*_cost` to a value that, because of the if statement, is ALWAYS going to be a necessarily incorrect value. 
The `*_cost = entered` line will ONLY execute when the program is going through its "invalid input" code. The program only prints "invalid input" when entered is not a legal value. Therefore _cost can only be set to an illegal value.
To solve your problem, put the `*_cost = entered` after the do-while loop.
I'm not sure why you aren't just using std::cin to read the data directly, rather than converting the standard input to an instance of std::string and then to an istringstream.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the first `*_cost = entered` out of the `do .. while` block to become the first statement after it. Having done that, you'll see a further refactor helpful although not required.

```
while(!(stin >> entered))
{
    cout << "invalid input" << endl;
    stin.clear();
    getline(cin, input);
    stin.str(input);
}
*_cost = entered;
```

Answer (score 0):

while executing `*_cost = entered;` in your code, `entered` is invalid.

I have just corrected your code with your original intention

```
bool Item::setCost(string input) {
    bool ret_val = true;
    float entered = 0.0;
    istringstream stin;
    stin.str(input);

    while ( !(stin >> entered) ) {  // loop till you read a valid input 
        if ( !stin.rdbuf()->in_avail() ) {
            ret_val = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    *_cost = entered;
    return ret_val;
}
```

`stin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` can be used to get the count of available characters ready to be read in from a stringstream, you can use that to check if your stringstream is "empty."

For example if you want to extract an float from a istringstream but you get somthing else (fail condition) and then see if there were any left over characters (ie. numeric) you could check if `stin.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0`.